# libxml - getting attributes

Tags: c++, xml, libxml2

I'm using LibXML. I use the xml file:

```
<all>
<material name1= "AS4C" name2="IPS06"/>
    <associated name1="IMA_1" name2="IPS05"/>
    <associated name1="IMA_2" name2="IPS05"/>
    <associated name1="IMA_3" name2="IPS05"/>
    <associated name1="AS4C" name2="IPS05"/>
    <associated name1="AS3C" name2="IPS05"/>
<material />

<material name1="IMA_1" name2="IPS06"/>
    <associated name1="IMA_1" name2="IPS05"/>
    <associated name1="AS4C" name2="IPS05"/>
    <associated name1="HTA_M" name2="IPS05"/>
    <associated name1="IMA_M21E" name2="IPS05"/>
<material />
</all>
```

I'm trying to check if for example **associated name1="IMA_3" name2="IPS05"/** exists in **material name1= "AS4C" name2="IPS06"/**. But the result is empty (xmlXPathNodeSetIsEmpty(result->nodesetval)
I think that the path is not true.

```
string s_mat1 = "AS4C";
string s_spec1 = "IPS06";
string s_mat2 = "IMA_3";
string s_spec2 = "IPS05";
sPath <<  "/all/material[@name1=\"" << s_mat1 << "\"][@name2=\"" << s_spec1 << "\"]/associated[@name1=\"" << s_mat2 << "\"][@name2=\"" << s_spec2 << "\"]";
result = xmlXPathEvalExpression((xmlChar *) sPath.str().c_str(), ctxt);
if(xmlXPathNodeSetIsEmpty(result->nodesetval)){
    cout << "empty" << endl;
}
if (result->type == XPATH_NODESET) {

        xmlNodePtr matNode = result->nodesetval->nodeTab[0];
        xmlChar *matNode2 = xmlNodeGetContent(matNode);

        struct _xmlAttr* matAttr = matNode->properties;

        while (matAttr) {
            cout << "matAttr :" << string((char *)matAttr->name) << endl;
            if (string((char *)matAttr->name)=="name1" && matAttr->children){
                string name1= string((char *)matAttr->children->content);
                cout << "___ name1==" << name1<< endl;

                xmlChar* value = xmlNodeListGetString(matNode->doc, matAttr->children, 1);
                cout << "value ==" << string((char *)value)  << endl;

            }
            else if (string((char *)matAttr->name)=="name2"){
                string name2= string((char *)matAttr->children->content);
                cout << "___ name2==" << name2<< endl;
            }
            matAttr = matAttr->next;
        }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have any materialName or specName attributes in your XML but instead name1 and name2.

Comment: sorry that was a typing error, i edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if not another typo (but would be more unusual), but your xml data does not fit to your query. I would guess your xml file is not what you actually intend it to be, instead it should be:

```
<material name1= "AS4C" name2="IPS06">
    <associated name1="IMA_1" name2="IPS05"/>
    <associated name1="IMA_2" name2="IPS05"/>
    <associated name1="IMA_3" name2="IPS05"/>
    <associated name1="AS4C" name2="IPS05"/>
    <associated name1="AS3C" name2="IPS05"/>
</material>

<material name1="IMA_1" name2="IPS06">
    <associated name1="IMA_1" name2="IPS05"/>
    <associated name1="AS4C" name2="IPS05"/>
    <associated name1="HTA_M" name2="IPS05"/>
    <associated name1="IMA_M21E" name2="IPS05"/>
</material>
</all>;
```

Note, that in your example the `material` and `associated` nodes are siblings, but now `associated` is a child of `material`.